# Basic question for javascript professionals

Tags: javascript

I created this function to work only if the goerror variable is = 0. 
That is, if the variable is goerror = 1, it will execute the regad() function or not ?

```html
  var goerror = 0;
player.on('adserror', function() {
  var goerror = 1;
});

if(goerror == 0){
 player.on('adstart', function() {
  regad();
 });

 player.on('adplaying', function() {
  regad();
 });
}
```

Comment: `var goerror = 1;` is locally (to the function) scoped and does not change the global scoped variable of the same name - basic scoping issue

Comment: "var goerror = 1;"  has to become  "goerror = 1;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are redeclaring geoerror inside function again while updating value, that won't make any change to global varible

You should not check the geoerror before writing event handler function, because initially it won't run, instead you can check this while event handler executes, check the code below

```
var goerror = 0;
player.on('adserror', function() {
  goerror = 1;
});

player.on('adstart', function() {
    if(goerror == 0)
        regad();
});

player.on('adplaying', function() {
    if(goerror == 0)
        regad();
});
```